# run script from directory using cron

Tags: 14.04, cron

I have this in my crontab:

```
59 23 * * * /home/peter/Documents/script.py > /home/peter/Documents/log.log 2>&1
```

But I keep getting `/bin/sh: 1: /home/peter/Documents/script.py: not found` in log.log file. I even tried add cd  before /home for the script and it still won't work. what else do I need to do?

ls -la output: `-rwxrwxr-- 1 peter peter 603 Jul 18 16:08 /home/peter/Documents/script.py`

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of  `ls -la /home/peter/Documents/script.py`

Comment: Correct the typo in your crontab: `/home/peter/Documents/log.log`, there is a missing `/`.

Comment: I just edited what you suggested

Comment: Do you have an encrypted home folder?

Comment: I don't. I actually got it to work by removing the shebang line from script.py and doing `59 23 * * * cd /home/peter/Documents/ && python3 script.py > /home/peter/Documents/log.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, enough comments **;)** …

Edit your script an add the right shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```